# How to track if input is being changed (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, input

I have the following code:

```
jQuery('#hexVal').change(function() {
    var hexvarval = jQuery('#hexVal').val();
    jQuery('#thumbnail_hover_color').val(hexvarval);
});
```

Basically, I want to change value of `#thumbnail_hover_color` INPUT every time `#hexVal` INPUT is being changed. When I do it manually it works. When other jQuery script puts text to #hexVal then it doesn't update `#thumbnail_hover_color`.

Question: How do I trigger "change value" for one INPUT field each time the value is changed (anyhow) in other INPUT field? I want them to have ALWAYS the same value.

Comment: Are you sure this is in the `document.ready` ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. It works on manual input change. It only doesn't trigger "change" when other jQuery script puts there some value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're programmatically setting/changing the value of an input, you'll also have to programmatically trigger the change event (or call the same code as the change event handler). So, I guess you have two options:

```
jQuery('#hexVal').change(function() {
    var hexvarval = jQuery('#hexVal').val();
    jQuery('#thumbnail_hover_color').val(hexvarval);
});

jQuery('#hexVal').val('some value'); // changing the value
jQuery('#hexVal').trigger('change'); // triggering the change event handler
```

or

```
function changeHexVal() {
    var hexvarval = jQuery('#hexVal').val();
    jQuery('#thumbnail_hover_color').val(hexvarval);
}

jQuery('#hexVal').change(changeHexVal);

jQuery('#hexVal').val('some value'); // changing the value
changeHexVal(); // calling the 'change' event handler function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the `change` event of `#hexVal` with below code. Trigger this event wherever you are setting the value of `#hexVal` in your code.

```
jQuery('#hexVal').change();
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I detect if something (jQuery script) changed #hexVal input value? I can't detect that and that's the problem.

Comment: @LEOPiC - If you check OP's question carefully you will come to know "How do I trigger "change value" for one INPUT field". Hope you remove your downvote.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli the line of code you wrote is exactly the first line of code the OP posted, how is that of any help? That would solve the question if you ignored the content of the question and only read the title.

Comment: @LEOPiC - How is it the same line? Don't you see any difference? If you are not aware that is one of the way to trigger the `change` event. You should clear out your basics before down voting on any answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't see the diference, the OP has: jQuery('#hexVal').change(function() { ... }); and you have: jQuery('#hexVal').change(); how is jQuery('selector').event different from jQuery('selector').event ?

Comment: @LEOPiC - `jQuery('#hexVal').change()` this line of code will trigger the `change` event and all the change event handlers will be executed where as ` jQuery('#hexVal').change(function() { ... });` will attach a handler to the `change` event, it will not trigger it.

Comment: Tale a look the documentation for your better understanding http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: You are absolutely right, my apologies for the incorrect downvote.

Comment: If you realized your mistake you can now remove the down vote